# Performance improve in ASP.NET Through Aplication Level Cache?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have developed an dotnet application and it contains a lot of data. Because of heavy data, application consumes more bandwidth and slow speed. Is there any way to improve performance through Application level cache. I have studied about redis but its key-value while i am using sql server. I want a solution so table load from the sql server to web server cache so it has to not hit the sql again and again thanks.

Comment: According to your description, you application is an dotnet application, instead of dotnet core application, right? If that is the case, we could cache Static Content, cache whole or partial page response using OutputCache Attribute and cache the shared data, more details trips, refer the [Three Ways To Improve Performance Using Caching In ASP.NET MVC Applications](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/3-ways-to-improve-performance-using-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-application/). Besides, for the large data displaying, you could also try to use paging.

Comment: Its dotnet core web application with angular frontend.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core supports several different caches. The simplest cache is based on the [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#systemruntimecachingmemorycache).

To use the In-Memory Cache in Asp.net core, you can use the [System.Runtime.Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)/[MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) ([NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Caching/)), then, you can register IMemoryCache in ConfigureServices using:

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

Then, in the controller, you can refer the following code to use cache to store the data.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
    }
    public IActionResult CacheTryGetValueSet()
    {
         DateTime cacheEntry;

        // Look for cache key.
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.Entry, out cacheEntry))
        {
            // Key not in cache, so get data.
            cacheEntry = DateTime.Now;

            // Set cache options.
            var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                // Keep in cache for this time, reset time if accessed.
                .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

            // Save data in cache.
            _cache.Set(CacheKeys.Entry, cacheEntry, cacheEntryOptions);
        }

        return View("Cache", cacheEntry);
    }
```

More detail information, check [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#systemruntimecachingmemorycache)